# The density of a pushforward probability measure: the reciprocal of the Jacobian determinant?

Tags: measure-theory, density-function, change-of-variable, jacobian, pushforward

$
\def\dee{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}}
\def\Jac#1{\mathop{\mathbf{J}_{#1}}}
$

I'm confused about how to use the change of variable formula to describe the density of a pushforward measure.  My question boils down to: which of the two formulae, (1) and (2) below, is the correct one?

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with density $\rho_X$ wrt the Lebesgue measure and let $Y=f(X)$ be another random variable, where $f$ is a deterministic invertible transformation.  *What is the probability density function of $Y$?*  [Just to be clear, the connection with the push-forward is: Denote by $P_X$ the law of $X$. Then the law of $Y$ is $P_Y = P_X \circ f^{-1} = {({P_X})}_\sharp f$, the push-forward of $P_X$ by $f$.]

For any measurable set $E$ of outcomes for $Y$, the probability measure of that set is

$$
\begin{align}
P_Y(E) = P_X(f^{-1}(E))
&= \int_{f^{-1}(E)} \rho_X(x) \dee x\\
&= \int_{E} \rho_X(f^{-1}(y)) \left|\frac{\dee}{\dee y}f^{-1}(y)\right|\dee y
\end{align}
$$

(using the [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula) formula for [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability)) so the density of $Y$ is

$$
\rho_Y(y) = \rho_X(f^{-1}(y)) \left|\frac{\dee}{\dee y}f^{-1}(y)\right|
$$

The derivative in this expression generalizes to the Jacobian determinant in multivariate case (when $f$ is a diffeomorphism, I gather), giving the following formula for the density (see, e.g. [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/728080/ruy))

$$
\tag{1}
\rho_Y(y) = \rho_X(f^{-1}(y)) \left|\det\Jac{f^{-1}}(y)\right|
$$

**However**, a few sources (for example, [Betancourt's notes](https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/probability_theory.html#42_probability_density_functions) see section 4.2, and some implementations, like [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-a-pushforward-distribution-17758c1fd542))* give a similar expression but with the *reciprocal* of the Jacobian determinant, as

$$
\tag{2}
\rho_Y(y) = \rho_X(f^{-1}(y)) \frac1{\left|\det\Jac{f^{-1}}(y)\right|}
$$

It can't be the case that (1) and (2) both hold in general!  Is (2) just a typo, or have I misunderstood the notation they use?

I know that $(\frac{\dee}{\dee x}{f}(x))^{-1}=\frac{\dee}{\dee y}{f^{-1}}(y)$ (by the inverse function theorem). This generalizes to $(\Jac{f}(x))^{-1}=\Jac{f^{-1}}(y)$. So, I think the correct version of (2) would be ($2^\star$):

$$
\tag{2$^\star$}
\rho_Y(y) 
= \rho_X(f^{-1}(y)) \frac1{\left|\det\Jac{f}(x)\right|}\\
= \rho_X(x) \frac1{\left|\det\Jac{f}(x)\right|}
$$

or, in the simpler one-dimensional case,

$$
\displaystyle
\rho_Y(y) = \rho_X(f^{-1}(y)) \frac1{\left|\frac{\dee}{\dee x}{f}(x)\right|} \\
= \rho_X(x) \frac1{\left|\frac{\dee}{\dee x}{f}(x)\right|}
$$

But I don't know why you would write it that way (since you want an expression where $y$ is the variable, not $x$), instead of the way in $(1)$.

Have I just made a silly mistake reading the notations?  Is $(2)$ somehow correct?

---

*EDIT: I think I may be interpreting Betancourt's notation wrong.  I now think any sources for $(2)$ are either based on a misunderstanding or a typo.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity lets assume $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable and bijective
and denote its inverse function by $g\,.$ Then
$$\tag{1}
f'(x)=\frac{1}{g'(f(x))}
$$
and, by ordinary change of variables from elementary calculus,
$\def\dee{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}}$
\begin{align}
P_Y(E) &= P_X(f^{-1}(E))
= \int_{f^{-1}(E)} \rho_X(x) \dee x=\int_{g(E)} \rho_X(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f'(x)} \dee x\tag{2}\\
&=\int_{g(E)}\rho_X\big(g(f(x))\big)\frac{f'(x)}{f'(x)}\dee x
=\int_{g(E)}\rho_X\big(g(y)\big)\frac{1}{f'(x)}\dee y\tag{3}\\
&= 
\int_{E} \rho_X\big(g(y)\big)\,g'(y)\dee y\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}
In other words,  when the density of $X$ is $\rho_X(x)$ then the density of $Y=f(X)$ is
$$\tag{5}
\rho_X\big(g(y)\big)\,g'(y)=\rho_X(f^{-1}(y))\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(y))}\,.
$$
One-line proof of (1). From $g(f(x))=x$ it follows by differentiation from the chain rule that
$$\tag{6}
g'(f(x))f'(x)=1\,.
$$
QED

Comment: I used the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statements). Please describe the equations you are asking about more clearly (comments support Mathjax). I also believe that looking at the case $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ from first principles will allow to get to the very bottom of your question without looking at any reference. I would not take an interest in this question if I had not the same type of riddle every now and then.

Comment: Okay, now I am quite convinced that the correct version is my first one: $\rho_Y(y)=\rho_X(f^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)\right|$.

Comment: Absolutely. I had exactly that error in (3) which I now corrected. Thanks!

Comment: In Betancourt's notes I only see \begin{align}
\pi_{*} (y) 
&= \pi(g^{-1}(y)) |J(g^{-1}(x))|^{-1}
\\
&= \pi(g^{-1}(y))
\left| \frac{ \partial g}{\partial x} (g^{-1}(y)) \right|^{-1}.
\end{align} The line with the Jacobian of $g^{-1}$ drives me nuts. His next line seems OK though. His $g$ is my $f$.

Comment: Yes, it was that first line that my question was motivated by--it's that that I was trying to understand.  But I think it just has a typo.

Comment: Lets rather just clean up that comment section here by deleting most of them. We can restart the discussion when a really serious problem comes up. typos in maths are ubiquitous.