# Change of variables in $d$-dimensional space

Tags: real-analysis, change-of-variable

I have the following problem: Setting, for $\lambda>0$, $x_\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^d$,
$$
(g_\lambda u)(x):=\lambda^{-\frac{d-2}{2}}u\left(\frac{x-x_\lambda}{\lambda}\right)\quad e \quad [(g_\lambda)^{-1}u](x):=\lambda^{\frac{d-2}{2}}u(\lambda x+x_\lambda).
$$

Show that $\Vert g_\lambda u\Vert_{\dot{H}^1}=\Vert u\Vert_{\dot{H}^1}=\Vert (g_\lambda)^{-1}u\Vert_{\dot{H}^1}$.

But when I use the change of variables $y=\frac{x-x_\lambda}{\lambda}$, I got

$$
\Vert g_\lambda u\Vert_{\dot{H}_x^1}= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\nabla (g_\lambda u)|^2dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\nabla\left[\lambda^{-\frac{d-2}{2}}u\left(\frac{x-x_\lambda}{\lambda}\right)\right]\right|^2dx$$$$=\lambda^{-(d-2)}\lambda^d\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\nabla u(y)|^2dy=\lambda^2\Vert u\Vert_{\dot{H}^1}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know how the change of variables formula works for the much simpler but closely related integral $\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(\alpha x)\,dx$ when you substitute $y=\alpha x$? Hint: you need the determinant of a Jacobi matrix.

Comment: Isnt $\alpha^{-d}$ the determinant of the Jacobi matrix in this case? Because is a diagonal matrix with $\alpha$ in the main diaogonal

Comment: Please figure out yourself if it is $\alpha^d$ or $\alpha^{-d}\,.$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642808/949989) for example how to do it from scratch. Suppose I answer your last question with yes/no. What if I err? Hint is given. Work it out.